# Cast generic List to implemented interfaces C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, generics, .net-core

I want to filter a list inside a class that implemented some interface.

Here is my codes:

```
public interface IChild
{
    public string Nth { get; set; }
}
public interface IChild<T> : IChild
{
    public T Parent { get; set; }
}
public class TeacherChilren : IChild<Teacher>
{
    public Teacher Parent { get; set; }
    public string Nth { get; set; }
}
public interface Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public interface ChildOwner<T> : Parent where T : IChild
{
    public List<T> Children { get; set; }
}
public class Teacher : ChildOwner<TeacherChilren>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TeacherChilren> Children { get; set; }
}
var list = new List<Teacher>{
    new Teacher()
};
Console.WriteLine(new Teacher() is ChildOwner<IChild>);
Console.WriteLine(list is List<ChildOwner<IChild>>);
```

I want to cast the list but the output is false.

Why output is false?

My design is wrong?

what is the solution?

Comment: `list.OfType<ChildOwner<IChild>>()` might be useful

Comment: You have two hierarchies defined, but you only need one.

Comment: Why do you need generics? The way I read the code you can get rid of all the generic definitions and just work with `IChild` and `IParent`.

Comment: @john-alexiou I want to be able to filter children base on child property.

Comment: NB: The correct spelling is `Children`, not `Chilren`, even though the `d`  is silent [in some dialects of English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/children).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cast `ChildOwner` to `Teacher`, then it is not eligible.

Let me show an example:

```
public class Vehicle 
{

}

public class Plane : Vehicle
{
    public PilotWheel PilotWheel { get; set; }
}
```

`Vehicle` cannot be cast to `Plane` type. Because where we can take `PilotWheel` value? However, `Plane` can be casted to `Vehicle` type.

### UPDATE:

> I want to cast teacher to childowner not opposite.

It is illegal too. Let's see this example:

```
class Animal { }

class Sheep : Animal { }

class Wolf : Animal { }
```

and:

```
List<Sheep> sheep = new List<Sheep>();
List<Animal> animals = (List<Animal>)sheep; // illegal
```

Why is the cast illegal?

Let's suppose it was legal. Now we add another line:

```
animals.Add(new Wolf());
```

So it would be disaster if casting will work

Read more here about [Covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) in generics

### UPDATE 1

> For list is reasonable but why cant cast teacher to chilowner?

You can. Let me show an example:

```
Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
ChildOwner<TeacherChilren> foo = teacher;
```

Comment: I want to cast teacher to childowner not opposite.

Comment: @mahmood please, see my updated answer

Comment: @mahmood as a good practice it is better to have one question per topic. It is beyound this topic. You can create new question and write your goal and what you want to achieve. If you feel that my reply is helpful, then you can upvote or mark my reply as an answer to simplify the future search of other users. [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/309682)

Comment: For list is reasonable but why cant cast teacher to chilowner?

Comment: @mahmood please, see my updated answer

Comment: What about this: ChildOwner<IChild> foo = teacher;  Thats what i dont know

Comment: IEnumerbale<Animal> animals = (IEnumerbale<Animal>)sheep; this is legit

Comment: @mahmood because `IChild` is not equal to `ChildOwner<TeacherChilren>`